# How can I change TS object array format?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

[Array which I want change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lGZi.png)

I have got this array in TypeScript, I want it change as bellow.

```
list = [{id : 1, name : bus, active : 1}, {id : 2, name : car}]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your input is not a valid js array as one of the nested objects doesn't have a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the input and reduce each element to an object.

```js
const list = [
  [{ id: 1 }, { name: 'bus' }, { active: 1 }],
  [{ id: 2 }, { name: 'car' }],
];

const result = list.map((el) => {
  return el.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return { ...acc, ...curr };
  }, {});
});

console.log(result);
```